# What do the yellow lashes/wings on the B737 PFD indicate?

Tags: flight-instruments, boeing-737

When I was looking at a YouTube clip of a B737 doing a landing, I couldn't help but notice something on the PFD:

**What do these yellow lashes/wings indicate on the artificial horizon?**
[image: Picture of PFD with arrows pointing to two yellow features]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ag6rlU-CDwY) (Added green arrows for question clarity)</sup>

They were on for the entire approach and remained on even after touchdown.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They display the maximum pitch that can be exercised with the current configuration of the aircraft.

Using data which is measured in modern airliners, a maximum pitch angle can be calculated and displayed to the pilot on the primary display. It is described fully [on this page](http://www.basicairdata.eu/knowledge-center/measurement/in-flight-angle-of-attack-usage/) (h/t @mins)

> With airplane aerodynamic specific data and the angle of attack measurement, we can have an effective pitch limit indicator PLI. A pitch limit indicator informs the user about the current difference between $max(\alpha)$ and the current $\alpha$. In many commercial airplane the pitch limit indicator is integrated within the glass cockpit, as shown in Figure 3; with this setup the pilot has a real-time indication of how much can pull on the column.

Comment: Does this indicate the limit of pitch, or actually the limit of AoA?

Comment: What are those markings to be compared to? In the video they seem to be "fixed to the screen" while the blue/brown horizon indicater moves behind them? I do not suppose the idea is to tell the pilot "don't pitch more than 12 degrees _below_ the horizon", but then what is it that should be kept from crossing the yellow marks?

Comment: @Steve If I had to guess, it's the pitch that will result in max alpha.  I'm not sure how wing loading is taken into account...  I would guess that if you pull up and increase the G loading, then the max pitch angle should decrease even though the max alpha is the same.  Increase G loading enough, and you should be able to bring the max pitch angle down to meet the current pitch angle.  Again, just guessing.